# Warp shader behaves itself differently on mobile and desktop

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, glsles

I try to implement warp shader (black hole). It works great on desktop, but it looks wrong on mobile devices. The problem is in its size. When I increase the size of black hole the warped edges disappear. If it has very small size it looks as I want. I am using LibGDX.

How it should look like (Desktop):
[image]

How it looks on mobile device with the same size:
[image]

When I decrease the size the warped edges appears:
[image]

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec2 a_position;

void main()
{   
   gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);    
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_res;
uniform float u_size;

// Gravitational field at 
// position pos, given a black hole
// of mass m at position center
// (ignoring G constant)
vec2 Fgrav(float m, vec2 center, vec2 pos)
{
    vec2 dir = center - pos;
    float distance = length(dir);
    dir /= distance;
    return dir * (m / (distance*distance));
}

void main(void)
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy; 
    vec4 sceneColor;    

    vec2 blackHoleCenters = vec2(u_res.xy*.5);                                      
    vec2 netGrav = Fgrav( (50. - u_size) * 500., blackHoleCenters, gl_FragCoord.xy);                
    float netGravMag = length(netGrav);

    if(netGravMag < 1.0)        
    {
        texCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy + netGrav*((50. - u_size) * 15.0))/u_res.xy;            
    }
    else texCoord.xy=vec2(.5,.5);   

    sceneColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord);    
    gl_FragColor = sceneColor;  
}
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

That's how I get `u_size` parameter:

```
public float getDistance(Camera cam){
    return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cam.position.x, 2) + Math.pow(cam.position.y, 2) + Math.pow(cam.position.z, 2));
}

public void render(Camera cam, Mesh quad) {
    program.begin();        
    program.setUniformf(u_size, getDistance(cam));

...
```

Initializing of camera:

```
cam = new PerspectiveCamera(64, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
cam.position.set(0f, 0.0f, 30.0f);
cam.lookAt(0,0.0f,0);
cam.near = 0.1f; 
cam.far = 450f;
cam.update();
```

So, the initial value of `u_size` is `30`.

Comment: What range is the `u_size` parameter in? Maybe if the precision is too low, `50. - u_size` is effectively `50.`. You could try using `highp`, but this is only a hint, and on some devices is no better than `mediump`.